# Can I make a QStandardItem editable from one view but not the other?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Consider the snippet below that creates two item models and views for a single item:

```
item = QStandardItem("my item")

item_model_1 = QStandardItemModel()
item_model_1.appendRow(item)

item_model_2 = QStandardItemModel()
item_model_2.appendRow(item)

view_1 = QTreeView()
view_1.setModel(item_model_1)

view_2 = QTreeView()
view_2.setModel(item_model_2)
```

I would like the user to be able to view the item from either view, but have it editable from only one view. Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot add the same item to more models, so what you're asking is invalid in nature. You may eventually *clone* items, but the new items will be completely unrelated from the original ones (so, editing the original won't change the clone). It's also unclear if you want to make the *whole* model not editable or just specific items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same model for both views

```
item = QStandardItem("my item")

item_model = QStandardItemModel()
item_model.appendRow(item) 

view_1 = QTreeView()
view_1.setModel(item_model)

view_2 = QTreeView()
view_2.setModel(item_model)
```

and disable the edit trigger for one of the view

```
view_2.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
```

You should also read

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html#using-views-with-an-existing-model